# Chart.js remove gridline

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Stuck on a chart.js item as the docs don't seem to be particularly clear.

Simply trying to remove a gridline from the chart.  I tried both the old syntax that was referenced here in Stack overflow:

```
options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
```

And the new syntax:

```
options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        grid: {
          drawBorder: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Neither work...

Here's my Snippet:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 10, 5, 8, 11]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        }
      }],
      y: {
        grid: {
          drawBorder: false
        }
      },
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The property you are looking for is called `display` instead of `drawBorder`, also your `xAxes` are defined in the wrong way, you were using v2 syntax instead of v3

Example:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 10, 5, 8, 11]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      },
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: LeeLenalee curious, how did you solve for this?  When I look at their docs [link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/gridlineoptions.html), I see there is a `display: boolean` but there's nothing that clearly identifies it falls under the tree `grid` nor under the `x` or `y` under `scales`.  Is there full element tree somewhere, or better docs you're aware of?

Comment: for example here in the scales docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/cartesian/linear.html#linear-axis-specific-options under the sub title you can see namespace and thats where you know to put the config

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution.

Looks like lot of configuration has changed in the new version.

[Reference from documentation here.](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/grid.html)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 10, 5, 8, 11]
    }]
  },
   options: {
     scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
           drawOnChartArea:false
         }
      },
       y: {
        grid: {
           drawOnChartArea:false
         }
      }
    }
   }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by setting the color of the gridlines to white like so:

```
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        color: '#ffffff'
      }
    }]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Dyvd for the answer!  It seems in the latest version of chart.js they have on their cdn - 3.2.1 - that this solution no longer works.  Apparently the element tree under `scales: { }` has changed pretty significantly, but I can't find any clear documents that support the current element tree.  LeeLenalee's solution (above) solved for the issue.

Comment: Ah okay, nice to hear. Thanks for the feedback